# Error flutter build ios: No type or protocol named 'FlutterPlugin'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I successfully build APK but when I try to build iOS: flutter build ios, this is the results:

No type or protocol named 'FlutterPlugin'

[image: Many plugins show errors like this]

My questions are:

1. Why did this error happen? the android version all normal.
2. How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Same issue here. Do you know what's hapenning?

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: i have same issue in flutter 1.22.3